# access denied when create task schedule in c#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

i want to create a schedule task  in root folder . this is my code

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "notepad";
    td.Principal.UserId = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.InteractiveToken;
    td.Triggers.Add(new LogonTrigger() { Enabled = true });
    td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
    td.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = false;
    td.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = false;
    td.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = TimeSpan.Zero;            

    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", null, null));
    // Register the task in the root folder
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Browser", td);
}
```

The application gives "access denied", even though my user is administrator!

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

[image]

Comment: Your error image and your posted code do not match, please don't simplify for this site, post your actual code.

Comment: are you sure you are administrator. Windows has many funny things associated with UAC that mess with aminstrativeness. Make sure you run the app from admin cmd shell (and run VS as admin too)

Comment: yes im sure, my user is admin but when i run my app as admin ,it create the task without problem.

Comment: Do you get an UAC prompt when running as you(r user)? If not add an `app.manifest` to your project. (In Visual Studio right click on the project and select "Add" > "New Item...". In the Window opening search for "application manifest file" (right upper side). Select "Application Manifest File" and click "Add".). Open the added `app.manifest`. There is a line `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` which is not in a comment. Replace `asInvoker` with `requireAdministrator`. The program will then make an UAC prompt pop up at start up.